# Converting list of datetimes to int

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas column that looks like this:

`df3[['days_till_all_arrive']]`

```
Int64Index([-7, 92], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([-20], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([83, 83], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([83, 83], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([92], dtype='int64')
...
Int64Index([91], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([91], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([91], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([92], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([92], dtype='int64')
```

It gets created with a function

```
def days_till_arrival(df):
    res = []
    for item in df['ETA']:
        item = pd.to_datetime(item)
        res.append((item - datetime.now()).astype('timedelta64[D]'))
    
    return res
```

`ETA` is a list of date values.
I use it like so:

```
df3['days_till_all_arrive'] = days_till_arrival(df3)
```

I want the values to be normal lists like so:

```
df3[['days_till_all_arrive']]

[-7, 92]
[-20]
[83, 83]
[83, 83]
[92]
...
[91]
[91]
[91]
[92]
[92]
```

I use `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` on a single value and it does convert it to the value I want of days, but when I use it in that function for multiple values I get more than [-7, 92], instead I get `Int64Index([-7, 92], dtype='int64')`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list` with [`Timedelta.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.days.html):

```
res.append(list((item - datetime.now()).days))
```

Comment: I still get the same output that looks like `Int64Index([-7, 92], dtype='int64')`.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Can you add list?